# How to install a local rpm file when building docker instance?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following docker file, I want to specifically install a rpm file that is available on my disk as I am building docker instance. My invocation of rpm install looks like this. Command
`RUN rpm -i chrpath-0.13-14.el7.x86_64.rpm` fails.

Is there a way to install rpm file available locally to new Docker instance?

```
FROM centos:latest
    RUN yum -y install yum-utils
    RUN yum -y install python-setuptools
    RUN easy_install supervisor
    RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
    RUN yum -y install which
    RUN yum -y install git
    # Basic build dependencies.
    RUN yum -y install  autoconf build-essential unzip zip
    # Gold linker is much faster than standard linker.
    RUN yum -y install  binutils
    # Developer tools.
    RUN yum -y install bash-completion curl emacs git man-db python-dev python-pip vim tar
    RUN yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel make
    RUN yum -y install swig
    RUN yum -y install wget
    RUN yum -y install python-devel
    RUN yum -y install ntp
    RUN rpm -i chrpath-0.13-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put this line before your `rpm -i` command:

```
ADD /host/abs/path/to/chrpath-0.13-14.el7.x86_64.rpm /chrpath-0.13-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Then you'll be able to do

```
RUN rpm -i chrpath-0.13-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Hmm. ADD failed for me with path outside the dockerfile context. It stripped the leading "/" and reported "no such file or directory". The reference page says "The <src> path must be inside the context of the build" and the reason "because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon." https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add  same limitation on COPY command

Comment: Don't you end up with a useless layer in your Docker image after executing this command? How can you achieve the same in just one clean layer that installs the RPM without leaving behind the copied package itself?

Answer (score 11):

As and addendum to what others have written here, rather than using:

```
RUN rpm -i xyz.rpm
```

You might be better off doing this:

```
RUN yum install -y xyz.rpm
```

The latter has the advantages that (a) it checks the signature, (b) downloads any dependencies, and (c) makes sure YUM knows about the package. This last bit is less important than the other two, but it's still worthwhile.

Comment: These days, you can get away with just `RUN yum install -y xyz.rpm`, as `localinstall` is no longer needed. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have your Dockerfile available at `/opt/myproject/.` Then first you have to put `rpm` inside `/opt/myproject` and then add

```
Add /xyz.rpm /xyz.rpm

RUN rpm -i xyz.rpm
```