# Quick way to add multiple RPM's to a dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image where I am trying to add a bunch of differnet RPM's.  I saw the topic on Github about adding a singular RPM -

[How to install a local rpm file when building docker instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082674/how-to-install-a-local-rpm-file-when-building-docker-instance/30083919)

However, I am trying to add quite a few different RPM's, so this method would be rather tedious.  Is there a more efficient way to just add a folder thats filled with RPM's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all forder with your RPMs

```
ADD /path_to_all_rpm_location_in_local_machine /path_to_place_rpm_in_docker
```

Or you can add each one PRM by one command `ADD`

Comment: So after I add the folder, would that install each one of the RPM's in there, or do I have to do a `RUN rpm -Uvh <nameofrpm>` for each of them?

Comment: have to do a RUN rpm -Uvh <nameofrpm> for each of them